# Unable to Handshake with iOS Device. Getting PList Error

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, usb, libimobiledevice

I want to Access iOS Device Connected with USB into my c# Application. i am using iMObileDevice Library for that.

But When i try to Handshake with Device than it Gives me Following Errors on Different Devices:-

```
  Additional information: An Lockdown error occurred. The error code was 
  PlistError
```

This is i am getting into iPhone 6S Plus

```
  Additional information: An Lockdown error occurred. The error code was 
  SslError
```

This Error i am Getting in iPhone 5.

Both OS Versions are above 10

Here is My code:-

```
            iDeviceHandle deviceHandle;
            idevice.idevice_new(out deviceHandle, udid).ThrowOnError();

            LockdownClientHandle lockdownHandle;
            lockdown.lockdownd_client_new_with_handshake(deviceHandle, out lockdownHandle, "Quamotion").ThrowOnError();

            string deviceName;
            lockdown.lockdownd_get_device_name(lockdownHandle, out deviceName).ThrowOnError();

            Console.WriteLine(deviceName);

            deviceHandle.Dispose();
            lockdownHandle.Dispose();
```

I am Unable to handshake with Device through lockdownd_client_new_with_handshake() Method.

Can anybody tell me what i am doing wrong and how to do it in proper way. My Task is to Install Application on Device.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It looks like you're using imobiledevice-net. Are you using the latest version of imobiledevice-net (1.2.1-r386)? Ssl errors etc are usually an indication that you're using an old version of imobiledevice-net.

Comment: Were you able to get this solved?

Comment: @lief480 I worked with compiled windows file of LibiMobileDevice instead of iMobileDevice to do my task

Answer (score 0):

With iMobileDevice-net (*latest stable 1.2.0.112*) I was getting the exact same error from lockdownd_client_new_with_handshake() method. I instead installed 1.2.1-r202, it seemed to resolve that issue.

I have also tried more recent releases such as r308, but I started to get the following error:
https://github.com/libimobiledevice-win32/imobiledevice-net/issues/54

Comment: Better Approach will be Compiled Code for LibiMobileDevice instead of this Package as you can customize it According to your requirements

Comment: Can you try version 1.2.31? We've done some work recently to fix the dll loading issues, and would appreciate feedback :).

Comment: I've tried version 1.2.76, it works just fine, no longer getting handshake error.